# Delete writable file with windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

Is seems to be a simple question but I didn't find any answer on google.
Simple `del /Q abc/stub/file.txt` doesn't work.
Error says Parameter format not correct - "stub".

Comment: [When you say that something didn't work, you have to say how it didn't work.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/21/9999675.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` is not the directory path separator in Windows, `\` is.

```
del /Q abc\file.txt
```

Comment: This answer is correct @Mady why didn't you check it and accept it if it works?  if not, say so.